# How to develop apps for XBox One?

Tags: windows, windows-10, xbox-one

I wish to develop apps for XBox One, not games, like Twitch. How do I get the SDK and how do I learn to develop apps for it? I am making a VOD app, so tutorials related to that will be helpful.

Is this possible using the Windows 10 SDK which has the Universal Windows Platform feature?

Links to tutorials, APIs would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any information about this? I'm trying to find information about web development guidelines for the Xbox One browser, but can't find anything. Can't even find contact information to reach out to them :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Windows 10 UWP is best option to get you started. Visual Studio 2015 has got all the necessary Windows 10 SDKs from which you can develop apps for multiple devices including Windows PC, Windows Phone, Tablets, XBOX, IOT devices and many more.

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx
http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers